# How can I split a column into 2 in the correct way?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, debian

I am web-scraping tables from a website, and I am putting it to the Excel file.
My goal is to split a columns into 2 columns in the correct way.

The columns what i want to split: "FLIGHT"

I want this form:

First example:  KL744 --> KL    and 0744

Second example: BE1013 --> BE and 1013

So, I need to separete the FIRST 2 character (in the first column), and after that the next characters which are 1-2-3-4 characters. If 4 it's oke, i keep it, if 3, I want to put a 0 before it, if 2 : I want to put 00 before it (so my goal is to get 4 character/number in the second column.)

How Can I do this?

Here my relevant code, which is already contains a formatting code.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(datatable,columns = cols)
df2["UPLOAD_TIME"] = datetime.now()
mask = np.column_stack([df2[col].astype(str).str.contains(r"Scheduled", na=True) for col in df2])
df3 = df2.loc[~mask.any(axis=1)] 

if os.path.isfile("output.csv"):
    df1 = pd.read_csv("output.csv", sep=";")
    df4 = pd.concat([df1,df3])
    df4.to_csv("output.csv", index=False, sep=";")

else:
    df3.to_csv
    df3.to_csv("output.csv", index=False, sep=";")
```

Here the excel prt sc from my table:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str) with [`zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'FLIGHT':['KL744','BE1013']})


df['a'] = df['FLIGHT'].str[:2]
df['b'] = df['FLIGHT'].str[2:].str.zfill(4)
print (df)
   FLIGHT   a     b
0   KL744  KL  0744
1  BE1013  BE  1013
```

I believe in your code need:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(datatable,columns = cols)
df2['a'] = df2['FLIGHT'].str[:2]
df2['b'] = df2['FLIGHT'].str[2:].str.zfill(4)
df2["UPLOAD_TIME"] = datetime.now()
...
...
```