# Extracting multiple strings from a Pandas row (single cell) into columns, with specific starting and ending text

Tags: python, pandas, regex, extract

I have a dataframe `df` where one column `'Images'` contains a bunch of HTML strings in each row from which I would like to extract URLs, that have a specific `Start` and `End` characters. Ideally they would then be turned into columns for each URL extracted.

`df` example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Description': ['USB Emergency Light Torch', 'USB RC LED DESKLAMP DL013', 'Green torch light with strap', 'Sensor Night Light W Switch A78'],
    'SKU': ['9023578-001001', '9023464-001001', '9023463-001001', '9023290-001001'],
    'Images': ['[{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/logo/stores/3/logo-b2b_1_-min.png"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/logo/stores/3/logo-b2b_1_-min.png"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/3f354f4955006fba9bb013076742094d/9/0/9023578-temp.jpg"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/3f354f4955006fba9bb013076742094d/9/0/9023578-3.jpg"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/3f354f4955006fba9bb013076742094d/9/0/9023578.jpg"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/f0229e02574c793c147c08297c074a46/9/0/9023578-temp.jpg"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/f0229e02574c793c147c08297c074a46/9/0/9023578.jpg"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/f0229e02574c793c147c08297c074a46/9/0/9023578-1.jpg"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/f0229e02574c793c147c08297c074a46/9/0/9023578-2.jpg"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/f0229e02574c793c147c08297c074a46/9/0/9023578-3.jpg"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/4c186adb30ce12db4dc6d068ea20241d/9/0/9023578-temp.jpg"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/wysiwyg/mageplus/_images/stores/3/logo-b2b_1_-min.png"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://image.useinsider.com/default/action-builder/instant-purchase.png"}]',
               '[{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/logo/stores/3/logo-b2b_1_-min.png"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/logo/stores/3/logo-b2b_1_-min.png"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/3f354f4955006fba9bb013076742094d/9/0/9023464-2.jpg"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/3f354f4955006fba9bb013076742094d/9/0/9023464-1.jpg"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/3f354f4955006fba9bb013076742094d/9/0/9023464.jpg"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/f0229e02574c793c147c08297c074a46/9/0/9023464-2.jpg"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/f0229e02574c793c147c08297c074a46/9/0/9023464.jpg"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/f0229e02574c793c147c08297c074a46/9/0/9023464-1.jpg"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/4c186adb30ce12db4dc6d068ea20241d/9/0/9023464-2.jpg"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/wysiwyg/mageplus/_images/stores/3/logo-b2b_1_-min.png"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://image.useinsider.com/default/action-builder/instant-purchase.png"}]',
               '[{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/logo/stores/3/logo-b2b_1_-min.png"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/logo/stores/3/logo-b2b_1_-min.png"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/3f354f4955006fba9bb013076742094d/9/0/9023463-2.jpg"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/3f354f4955006fba9bb013076742094d/9/0/9023463-1.jpg"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/3f354f4955006fba9bb013076742094d/9/0/9023463.jpg"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/f0229e02574c793c147c08297c074a46/9/0/9023463-2.jpg"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/f0229e02574c793c147c08297c074a46/9/0/9023463.jpg"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/f0229e02574c793c147c08297c074a46/9/0/9023463-1.jpg"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/4c186adb30ce12db4dc6d068ea20241d/9/0/9023463-2.jpg"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/wysiwyg/mageplus/_images/stores/3/logo-b2b_1_-min.png"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://image.useinsider.com/default/action-builder/instant-purchase.png"}]',
               '[{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/logo/stores/3/logo-b2b_1_-min.png"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/logo/stores/3/logo-b2b_1_-min.png"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/3f354f4955006fba9bb013076742094d/9/0/9023290-2_1.jpg"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/3f354f4955006fba9bb013076742094d/9/0/9023290.jpg"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/3f354f4955006fba9bb013076742094d/9/0/9023290-1_1.jpg"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/f0229e02574c793c147c08297c074a46/9/0/9023290-2_1.jpg"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/f0229e02574c793c147c08297c074a46/9/0/9023290-1_1.jpg"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/f0229e02574c793c147c08297c074a46/9/0/9023290.jpg"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/4c186adb30ce12db4dc6d068ea20241d/9/0/9023290-2_1.jpg"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://www.website.com.my/media/wysiwyg/mageplus/_images/stores/3/logo-b2b_1_-min.png"},{"Images":"","Images-src":"https://image.useinsider.com/default/action-builder/instant-purchase.png"}]']
})
```

Which looks like this:
[image]

Start: `https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/3f354f4955006fba9bb013076742094d`

End: `.jpg`

The other URLs and text can be ignored.

Desired Output (one URL per column, added to the end of the `df`; there might be more than 3 results, so the number of columns added is variable):

```
https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/3f354f4955006fba9bb013076742094d/8/9/8993791-temp.jpg
https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/3f354f4955006fba9bb013076742094d/8/9/8993791-3.jpg
https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/3f354f4955006fba9bb013076742094d/8/9/8993791.jpg
```

Here's an image example of the desired output in case:
[image]

So far I tried this code below (it only extracts to a single cell with "," as a joiner, haven't figured the column splitting yet) but the output is a seemingly empty cell with just `''` contained within:

```py
df['img_lines'] = df['Images'].str.findall('^https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/3f354f4955006fba9bb013076742094d.*\.jpg$').str.join(",")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done without regex using native string methods along with other built-in python modules: `json` and `itemgetter` (this one's not necessary but useful for convenience). In short, `Images` column contains json objects, so convert each item to a python list and simply search for the relevant URLs in it.

`json.loads` call creates a list of dictionaries and since you only care about the URLs under the `'Images-src'` key, get them using `itemgetter()` first. Then among these URLs, see filter the ones that starts and ends with the specific pattern you want.

```py
import json
from operator import itemgetter
df[['URL1','URL2','URL3']] = [[url for url in map(itemgetter('Images-src'), lst) if url.startswith('https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/3f354f4955006fba9bb013076742094d') and url.endswith('.jpg')] for lst in df['Images'].map(json.loads)]
```

If you insist on regex, `re.match` might be useful in the last step. The idea is to see if a string starts with the pattern you want; has whatever and ends with `.jpg`:

```py
import re
df[['URL1','URL2','URL3']] = [[url for url in map(itemgetter('Images-src'), lst) if re.match(r'https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/3f354f4955006fba9bb013076742094d.*\.jpg$', url)] for lst in df['Images'].map(json.loads)]
```

[image: res]

If there are variable number of columns, it is best to cast to a dataframe first and `join()` to `df` later to avoid a ValueError (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73443047/19123103)):

```py
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame([[url for url in map(itemgetter('Images-src'), lst) if url.startswith('https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/3f354f4955006fba9bb013076742094d') and url.endswith('.jpg')] for lst in df['Images'].map(json.loads)]).add_prefix('URL'))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

```
s1 = pd.Series(['aaa123.jpg', 'bca234.jpg', 'aaa425.gif',  'aaa234.jpg'])
```

s1

```
0    aaa123.jpg
1    bca234.jpg
2    aaa425.gif
3    aaa234.jpg
dtype: object
```

**Code**

if you want extract from 'aa' to '.jpg'

```
s1.str.extract('(aa.+.jpg)').dropna()[0]
```

result:

```
0    aaa123.jpg
3    aaa234.jpg
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

**in your example**

```
start = 'https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/3f354f4955006fba9bb013076742094d'
pat = '({}[^ ]+.jpg)'.format(start)
result = df['Images'].str.split('Images-src').explode().str.extract(pat).dropna()
```

result:

```
    0
0   https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/produ...
0   https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/produ...
0   https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/produ...
1   https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/produ...
1   https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/produ...
1   https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/produ...
2   https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/produ...
2   https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/produ...
2   https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/produ...
3   https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/produ...
3   https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/produ...
3   https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/produ...
```

make result to dataframe

```
result.groupby(level=0)[0].agg(list).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x))
```

output:

```
    0                                                   1                                                   2
0   https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/produ...   https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/produ...   https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/produ...
1   https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/produ...   https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/produ...   https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/produ...
2   https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/produ...   https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/produ...   https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/produ...
3   https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/produ...   https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/produ...   https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/produ...
```

concat output to your `df` and rename

Comment: The sample text above contains many URL strings and other unwanted characters within a single cell, with the desired output being 3 URLs. Wouldn't `str.extract` take out only the first instance per cell?

Comment: Your sample is not reproducible and it's hard to know exactly what you want. If you just want to extract all, use `extractall` function instead extract.

Comment: you can provide enough simple example instead head(4) of your data. In the future, provide simple and reproducible example. I left the code for your complex example

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are indexing wrong `column` of the `DataFrame`. Instead of `df['Images']`, you should do - `df['Images-src']`, as the links are in the latter `column`.

```py
df['Images-src'].str.findall('^https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/3f354f4955006fba9bb013076742094d.*\.jpg$').str.join(",")
```

EDIT:

Might not be the most efficient way. But, one thing you can do is convert the `HTML` string to `python object` using `json.loads`, and then create a new `DataFrame` and then filter the results.

```py
import json #Importing json module

for i in df['Images']: #Loops through the string
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(i)) #Creates a new DataFrame with prev string as python object
    print(df1['Images-src'].str.findall('^https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/3f354f4955006fba9bb013076742094d.*\.jpg$').str.join(","))
```

O/P:

```
0                                                      
1                                                      
2     https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/produ...
3     https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/produ...
4     https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/produ...
5                                                      
6                                                      
7                                                      
8                                                      
9                                                      
10                                                     
11                                                     
12                                                     
Name: Images-src, dtype: object
```

If you want to print like your desired output:

```py
a = df1['Images-src'].str.findall('^https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/3f354f4955006fba9bb013076742094d.*\.jpg$').str.join(",")

for i in a:
    if i != '':
        print(i)
```

O/P:

```
https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/3f354f4955006fba9bb013076742094d/8/9/8993791-temp.jpg
https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/3f354f4955006fba9bb013076742094d/8/9/8993791-3.jpg
https://www.website.com.my/media/catalog/product/cache/3f354f4955006fba9bb013076742094d/8/9/8993791.jpg
```

I'll leave the logical part to you for implementing it.

Comment: Hi, sorry if my formatting wasn't clear. But the sample text is everything contained within a single cell itself. `Images-src` isn't meant to be a column header

Comment: Can you share an extract of the output on how your `DataFrame` looks. It would really help in reproducing the error.

Comment: Alternatively, you can change your regex with respect to `json` strings, and remove unneccessary things first, like `" "`, `[ ]`, `{ }`, `:`, etc, and then initiate your `findall` function.