# Pandas Error "Columns must be same length as key" (I can't figure out how to fix in my specific example)

Tags: python, pandas

For some reason I keep getting the erorr "Columns must be same length as key" with this snippet of code.

```
def find_surebet(frame):
    # Error is between these two lines: Start
    frame[['btts_x_1', 'btts_x_2']] = frame['btts_x'].apply(       #specifically here
        lambda x: x.split('\n')).apply(pd.Series).astype(float)
    frame[['btts_y_1', 'btts_y_2']] = frame['btts_y'].apply(
        lambda x: x.split('\n')).apply(pd.Series).astype(float)
    # End
    frame['sure_btts1'] = (1 / frame['btts_x_1']) + (1 / frame['btts_y_2'])
    frame['sure_btts2'] = (1 / frame['btts_x_2']) + (1 / frame['btts_y_1'])
    frame = frame[['Teams_x', 'btts_x', 'Teams_y',
                   'btts_y', 'sure_btts1', 'sure_btts2']]
    frame = frame[(frame['sure_btts1'] < 1) | (frame['sure_btts2'] < 1)]
    frame.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    return frame
```

Does anyone know what the issue could be?

I've tried searching around stackoverflow but my problem seems to be a bit unique.

Comment: i presume you are attempting to pass a dict into the function and this is the cause of the error. However, because the question does not show how the function is called, it is hard to determine....   please provide sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73443047/19123103) may help you. It seems, when you split `frame['btts_x']`, it creates more than two columns.